# jmespath flatten multiple hash values

Tags: json, jmespath

Ideally, I want to write a query that returns a flat list output: `["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def"]` from the following JSON sample:

```
{
  "l_l": [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  "l_h_l": [
    { "n": [10,2,3] },
    { "n": [4,5,60] }
  ],
  "l_h_m": [
    {
      "n": {
        "1234": "abc",
        "2345": "bcd"
      }
    }, {
      "n": {
        "3456": "cde",
        "4567": "def"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The closest I can get is `l_h_m[].n.*` which returns the contents that I want as an unflattened list of lists:

```
[
  [
    "abc",
    "bcd"
  ],
  [
    "cde",
    "def"
  ]
]
```

jmespath lets you flatten lists of lists. Queries `l_l[]` and `l_h_l[].n[]` both returned flattened results, when the source json is structured that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your solution just required another flattening operator.

```
l_h_m[].n.*[]
```

returns

```
[
  "abc",
  "bcd",
  "cde",
  "def"
]
```